# Scrolling using jquery Firefox v/s IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, scroll

I am trying to scroll an element based on page scroll.
It works ok in firefox.

```
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scrollOffset = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (scrollOffset >= ele) {
                $("#UserDataTable thead").css({ "position": "relative" });
                $("#UserDataTable thead").css({ "background-color": "white" });
                $("#UserDataTable thead").css('top', scrollOffset);
            }
            else {
                $("#UserDataTable thead").css({ "position": "" });
                $("#UserDataTable thead").css('top', ele);
            }
        });
```

// ele here is the initial offset of the thead element I am trying to move.//

*The jsfiddle link is:*

http://jsfiddle.net/UnPAH/3/

But this just doesnt work in IE 8.

Can you please tell me the changes needed in IE8 to make this code work.

Comment: Try providing http://jsfiddle.net/ example

Comment: The code in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/UnPAH/3/ works in firefox, but doesnt work in IE8. Any workarounds for IE8, please.

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ele = $("table thead").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var cssProp = null,
            scrollOffset = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scrollOffset >= ele) {
            cssProp = {
                "background-color": "white",
                'padding-top': scrollOffset
            };
        } else {
            cssProp = {
                'padding-top': ele
            }
        }
        $("table thead tr:eq(0) th").css(cssProp);
        // or $("... td").css(cssProp); what ever elements you're using there
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't. IE8 doesn't seem to like - "position": "relative", 'top': scrollOffset - properties.

Comment: Actually adding such property to `thead` of a table is bad idea. Yes, it might not work, your concept is bad. Check for my update

Comment: I agree it is bad idea. Can you please suggest an IE8-fixed-header implementation like the jsfiddle I made. Thanks for the code above but it doesn't create a similar effect.

Comment: Actually no because the whole concept is bad using `<thead>` and suggesting something blinded on the whole scale is futile.
If possible use the `top` property on the table instead of thead

Comment: Actually I don't understand what is special/different about <thead>. The requirement is to keep the header unmoving, so I add corresponding properties to <thead>. And it does work in Firefox. I think it is just that IE8 doesn't work as usual. Can you point me to some URL that says properties should not be added to <thead>?

Comment: tables are different than block elements and `thead` is meant only to be a container so you can't expect to have cross browser behavior on positioning. You can play with  `display:block` on different elements but you risk to loose table properties.

Comment: As far as jsfiddle it supports IE8 in fullscreen result, press the **Share** button